# Combine multiple queries for checking existence of database records in different tables

Tags: .net, entity-framework

I have a function that requires validating the existence of some records in separate database tables. Currently I do this with separate queries so that I can return a relevant error message. A contrived example below:

```
var a = await context.EntityA.FirstOrDefaultAsync(e => e.id == entityAId);
var b = await context.EntityB.FirstOrDefaultAsync(e => e.id == entityBId);
var c = await context.EntityC.FirstOrDefaultAsync(e => e.id == entityCId);

if (a == default) return "Entity A ID is invalid";
if (b == default) return "Entity B ID is invalid";
if (c == default) return "Entity C ID is invalid";
```

This feels quite inefficient with three separate calls. Is there a way to combine these calls and still know which (if any) of the checks failed so that an appropriate response can be formed?

Comment: The answer is no, unless you use third-party libraries that offer "future queries". But it's really not a big deal to have separate calls (there's connection pooling). If you don't actually need the entity objects you better us `Any()`.

Comment: +1 on using `Any()`. Using `FirstOrDefault()` incurs the cost of loading an entire entity just to determine if a row is there. `Any()` will compose a query that simply returns whether a row exists of not. For something like an exists check by a PK/Indexed value, I also wouldn't bother with the overhead of an `async` call, just use the synchronous call. `async` is useful for keeping a server responsive while waiting for significant operations but it adds an overhead cost when it'd be faster to just run the queries in sequence.

Comment: I suggest creating a View across the tables you need and then tying the view to an entity. I've written a post about adding views to Entity Framework and it's pretty straight foward. https://khalidabuhakmeh.com/how-to-add-a-view-to-an-entity-framework-core-dbcontext. After adding the view, you can use the `Contains` keyword like you typically would.